# Qt outlined text without thinning font

Tags: qt, text

I want to draw outlined texts with Qt4.8, but I also want to keep the original shape and visibility of the font.
Currently, the outlines hide the text characters and have them look "thinner" than the originals.

Qt draws outline of text characters (and other shapes) with QPen.
QPen moves on the actual edge of a character and paints outside and **inside** of the edge line (See "Join Style" in QPen reference).

If you use a thicker pen, a text character looks thinner, while the total area taken by the character increases for the outline.
In other words, the outline erodes into the text character.

I want to have text characters keep their original shape and visibility while having "halo effect" from outlining.
I.e., I want to paint only the outside of edge lines.

What is the easiest way to implement such effect with Qt?
I came up with a few ideas, but I wonder if any of them is possible.

Plan A.

Draw texts with outline, then draw the same texts without outline over the outlined ones.

Unfortunately, QTextCursor doesn't support "overdrawing" or "overtyping", which you can do with classic typewriters.
There would be performance penalty, too.

Plan B.

Modify the Qt library so that it draws outline with QPen first, then fill inside with QBrush. QBrush would paint over the inside part of the outline and leaves only the outside intact.

I'm not sure if it works and I want to avoid modifying the Qt library if possible.

Plan C.

Switch the "CompositionMode" of the QPainter used for drawing text to "QPainter::CompositionMode_DestinationOver" temporarily.

To do this, I think I need to control the private and temporary QPainter created and used by Qt's text-manipulation widgets like QTextBrowser, but I don't know how it can be done.

I'm new to Qt programming and I use Qt 4.8.2 on X window.

You can see my problem by adding the following code lines (line 156-164) to /usr/lib64/qt4/examples/richtext/calendar/mainwindow.cpp, compiling and running it, and increasing the font size to 40 or larger.

```
 QTextCharFormat format = cursor.charFormat();
 format.setFontPointSize(fontSize);

 QTextCharFormat boldFormat = format;
 boldFormat.setFontWeight(QFont::Bold);

 // Additional code lines for green outline : line 156
 QPen    pen;
 pen.setStyle(Qt::SolidLine);
 pen.setWidthF(4);
 pen.setBrush(Qt::green);
 pen.setCapStyle(Qt::RoundCap);
 pen.setJoinStyle(Qt::RoundJoin);
 boldFormat.setTextOutline(pen);
 // The end of the additional code : line 164
```

If you can tell me the way to go and give me the initial clues, I'll appreciate your help very much.

Comment: Thanks to Ian Atkin, I looked into the "Painter Paths" example and started to think that my Plan B and C are against the fundamental design of Qt. With "Odd Even" fill rule, painting only the outside of edge lines with QPen and filling the inside with QBrush would produce ugly result with the "star shape" and "overlapping square and circle" example.

Comment: @Tapa, I've been leaving this question open for long time and I had no time to revisit it (I had been swamped by another project). I'm very sorry for my delayed reply. And, Yes, one of my colleagues solved the problem with a quite similar way to your solution. I accept your answer as the answer to my question. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a way, how to do such outlining for `QGraphicsView` text objects. I think, you can use it for any class based on `QTextDocument` (`QTextEdit`, for example). I've created a class based on `QGraphicsTextItem` and reimplemented its `paint` function:

```
void paint (QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem * option, QWidget * widget)
{ QTextCharFormat format;
  format.setTextOutline (QPen (Qt::white, 3, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap, Qt::RoundJoin)); // Color and width of outline
  QTextCursor cursor (this->document());
  cursor.select (QTextCursor::Document);
  cursor.mergeCharFormat (format);
  QGraphicsTextItem::paint (painter, option, widget);
  format.setTextOutline (QPen (Qt::transparent));
  cursor.mergeCharFormat (format);
  QGraphicsTextItem::paint (painter, option, widget);
}
```

The only bug I've noticed for this solution - when you edit text and start selecting some letters, clipping occurs. But it's almost unnoticeable. For non-editable items I can't find any bugs.

But if you want to outline `QPushButton` text (for example), then it is trivial (this problem has been discussed many times) - inside reimplemented `paintEvent` create `QPainterPath`, call `path.addText`, then use `painter.strokePath`, `painter.fillPath` - `strokePath` creates outline, and `fillPath` fills foreground.