# Stop QLabel text blending with background colour

Tags: qt, rendering, qwidget, antialiasing

### In short

I'm trying to get the text in my QLabel to paint as if it were over a black background, ignoring the real background colour.

### In depth

I have a `QLabel` in a green coloured widget, the text is anti-aliased and white, the anti-aliasing softens the edges of the text by blending with the green background colour.

Hardware detects the exact green colour and uses it like a green screen to display some techno-wizardry without also drawing over my software overlay, it makes the background look black.

The anti-aliased text has a fuzzy green halo where it has slightly changed the green colour and hardware doesn't overwrite it.

I want the text to be draw as if it were over a black background

### What I've tried

I have tried using a black opaque `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` to be drawn under the text, thus giving the text a black background to draw on, this led to a bigger green halo around the text.

I have tried setting various `QBrush`es in the label's `QPalette` for the `Qt::WindowText` and `Qt::Base` `ColorRole`s.

I have re-implemented the paintEvent and I am trying to use `style()->drawItemText(... )` to avoid re-implementing all the helpful alignment code.

I have tried intercepting the `QStyleOpt` parameter and setting its `QPalette`'s background colour to black, however that didn't change anything, I still get fuzzy, greenish text.

I have tried various `QBrush` and `QPen` colours in the `QPainter`.

I'm really close using a `QPainterPath` in an overidden `paintEvent` function (in a class extending QLabel) where I paint a black path of the text behind the text, then I call `QLabel::paintEvent` and let it draw the text over the top. The issue here is that in some cases the path is clipped to smaller than the widgets `rect()` on the left hand side, scope for another question I think!

### What I could try but haven't worked out yet

I could give the text a black outline as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13966868/921224) however I'm using a `QWidget` not a `QGraphicsView` text item, and then the black outline would still probably blend with the green background.

### Compromises I've already thought of and want to avoid

I could set the `QLabel` background to black, leaving large rectangles of black over the resulting overlay, unfortunately the labels are often much larger than the text being displayed.

I could stop the font being anti-aliased, this looks quite ugly and it stops all fonts being uniform across the product.

Comment: Try to disable antialiasing. `QFont font = label->font(); font.setStyleStrategy(QFont::NoAntialias); 
label->setFont(font);`

Comment: @Meefte I still want the font to be anti-aliased, will make that clearer in the question.

Comment: how about a transparent black background for the label?

Comment: @KarstenKoop I've also tried this, the text still blended with the visible background.

Comment: If you think black rectangles under the text would be OK if it didn't fill the whole label, then you could subclass `QLabel`, override `paintEvent`, and paint a black rectangle under the text by using `QFontMetrics` and some nice calculations.

Comment: @thuga That is certainly a decent compromise, I shall look into using that for now and wait and see if there is ever a more complete answer.